# Status de usuário zerados

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, perfil

Costumo acompanhar as alterações da minha reputação na página, mas dessa vez, ela bugou:

[image: Perfil bugado]

O gráfico de evolução da minha reputação sumiu, bem como as alterações na reputação, embora eu tenha 40925 pontos de reputação nesse momento e portanto deveria ter um longo histórico de alterações de reputação. O número de pessoas ajudadas e de posts editados caíram a zero.

Depois de trocar algumas abas nessa tela, as mudanças de reputação e o gráfico voltaram a aparecer, mas os outros dois continuam zerados.

Alguém mais consegue reproduzir esse problema?

Comment: Pra mim seus dados aparecem normalmente (mas pode ser pelo meu status de moderador). Parece que o sistema te escolheu pra lançar os bugs mais bizarros, hein? :)

Comment: Na aba "reputação" do seu perfil o histórico aparece normal?

Comment: Eu também vejo o seu perfil normal, com os dados todos

Comment: @bfavaretto Agora voltou a normal. Que estranho...

Comment: @Isac Agora voltou a normal. Que estranho...

Comment: Avisa se acontecer de novo que eu mudo o status

Comment: Aconteceu com mais um usuário. Deve ter sido temporário também, ele postou aqui no meta e apagou.